# jQuery modal window not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Modal window was working with the following code

```js
$(function() {
  $('.popup-open').click(function() {
    $('.popup-fade').fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
  $('.popup-close').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.popup-fade').fadeOut();
    return false;
  });
});
```

However, the window is opened by itself on page reloading. How to fix this?

I was trying put `visible: hidden` in the CSS, but if I do that then I need to use a method `(.popup-window).attr({'popup-window':'active'})`.
And in this case, it does not appear after reloading the page, but it works once before closing. It is not called even if I `removeAtr` from the window, and it does not appear anymore.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.popup-open').click(function() {
    $('.popup-fade').attr({
      "class": "popup-fade active"
    });
    $('.popup').attr({
      "class": "popup active"
    });
    return false;
  });
  $('.popup-close').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.popup-fade').fadeOut();
    $('.popup-fade').attr({
      "class": "popup-fade"
    });
    $('.popup').attr({
      "class": "popup"
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was here the modal window was changed from the bootrsap option, that is, by default it did not have `display: none;`
checked with the code constructor in google chrome noticed that fadein adds transparency to the window, I don't understand why visibility did not work

add `style="display: none;"` in style modal